# How to Calculate the sample mean, standard deviation, and variance in C++ from random distributed data and compare with original mean and sigma

Tags: c++, statistics, normal-distribution

I have Python script for Gaussian Normal distribution:

```
import numpy as np

x_mu = 25
x_sigma = 5
size = 1000

x_distribution = np.random.normal(x_mu, x_sigma, size)

#i am looking for help ONLY FOR this line below
test_distribution = np.std(x_distribution)  
print (test_distribution)
```

Updated: For large data (could be 10000 or only 500, so i will test it too), the sample mean and standard deviation have to be close to the original input (sigma and mean).

I am referring to this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/random-numbers-with-specific-mean-and-variance.html) and need to write in c++.

Please, if you know any libs in C++ or ideas, leave in comments or answer. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/c-api.array.html#functions

Comment: I am not asking how to write the normal distribution in C++. I got it this part. I am asking only how to verify the mean and sigma. People, why you are so mean and rude and downgrade my question.

Comment: Once you collect the sample data base on the distribution, sample mean and sample standard deviation shouldn't be hard to calculate. Are you looking for a one-liner or a built-in function specifically?

Comment: I am looking for how to test that my data was distributed normally. I plotted the data and looks correct. But, i want to check it in my code. Maybe, the answer is pretty obvious, but i just started learning the statistics and asked for help community :(  Python has verification, but it is using the Numpy lib. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

Comment: Sorry I'm still not sure what you want, do you just want to verify that sample mean and sample standard deviation is close to x_mu and x_sigma? We are all trying to help, so don't be discouraged. But we first have to be sure what you are asking

Comment: What I am still confused is "test_distribution = np.std(x_distribution)  
print (test_distribution)" only prints one number -- the standard deviation of the sample. So I'm not sure which part do you want the C++ code to be different. i.e. what should be changed in my sample standard deviation function below. If you want to print a histogram, it's also possible to do so in C++ by cout *

Comment: Hi @gchen, thanks for your comments. I have updated the header of my question and the body with "Updated" flag.

Comment: mean, variance and standard deviation can all be found in my stDev function below. Is that not what you are looking for? You can simply change the return type(i.e. a vector of 3 elements) or create a separate mean/variance function if you want.

Comment: ": For large data (could be 10000 or only 500, so i will test it too)"-- If you want to change the size of the sample, simply change the size variable(the 3rd variable in main) to whatever you want.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if you want anything to be changed

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is no standard deviation function C++, so you'd need to do write all the necessary functions yourself -- Generate random numbers and calculate the standard deviation.

```
double stDev(const vector<double>& data) {
    double mean = std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0) / data.size();
    double sqSum = std::inner_product(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), 0.0);
    return std::sqrt(sqSum / data.size() - mean * mean);
}

int main() {

    double x_mu = 25;
    double x_sigma = 5;
    size_t size = 1000;
    std::normal_distribution<double> x_distribution(x_mu, x_sigma);

    //generate random numbers and store them in a vector
    vector<double> data(size);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++) {
        data[i] = x_distribution(gen);
    }

    double test_distribution = stDev(data); 
    cout << test_distribution << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**:
To get mean, variance and standard deviation, you may create separate functions to do the calculations. One possible implementation would be:

```
double mean(const vector<double>& data) {
        return  std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0) / data.size();
}

double variance(const vector<double>& data) {
        double xBar = mean(data);
        double sqSum = std::inner_product(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), 0.0);
        return sqSum / data.size() - xBar * xBar;
}

double stDev(const vector<double>& data) {
     return std::sqrt(variance(data));       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have my code in C++.  I am looking for how to test that data was normally distributed.

Comment: Isn't np.std(x_distribution) just returning the standard deviation of the 1000 samples? Do you mean you want to calculate the chi-square statistics?

Comment: thanks for your help. I used your updated code and added to my function. Sorry, maybe my question was not clear and could not explain what i was looking for from first time. Thanks for being so patient :)